# how to change font of edited text using MFC in visual studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, fonts, mfc

I got assignment to make Dialog when pressing the right mouse button that will allow me to enter new text, change font and size. When I enter new text and choose font (and size) it is shown but font is unchanged. I used  Tool box to add Edit control to add text (when pressed Ok) and Button for font and size. In TxtDlg.cpp :

```
void CTxtDlg::OnOK()
{
    m_txtEdit.GetWindowText(m_text) ;
    CDialog::OnOK();
}

void CTxtDlg::OnBnClickedButton1()
{
     CFontDialog dlg;                    
     int response = dlg.DoModal(); //poziv dijaloga
     dlg.GetCurrentFont(&m_lf);
}
```

I also declared variable m_lf as LOGFONT in TxtDlg.h, so this part should be correct

```
CString m_text; 
CEdit m_txtEdit;
virtual void OnOK();
afx_msg void OnBnClickedButton1();
LOGFONT m_lf;
```

My guessing is that part of ProjectView.cpp part is incorrect(for font), should use ChangeFontIndirect but don't know how.

```
void CFesbView::OnRButtonDown(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{
    CFesbDoc*pDoc= GetDocument();                                           
    CTxtDlg dlg;        
    int response = dlg.DoModal();   //calling dialog

    if(IDOK == response)    
    {
        if(dlg.m_text.IsEmpty())    
            AfxMessageBox(L"You did not enter text");
        else
            pDoc->m_text = dlg.m_text;      // put text in document
        Invalidate();
    }


     pDoc->m_pos = point;    //point contain coordinates because text
                             //has to be written where clicked

                    //this is the incorrect part, also need to save text and font in document               
    CFont l_font;                                                       
    LOGFONT m_lf;
    if(IDC_BUTTON1==response){
    l_font.CreateFontIndirect(&m_lf);
    pDoc->m_lf = dlg.m_lf;  }


    CView::OnRButtonDown(nFlags, point);
}
```

This is the first time I'm using MFC so I don't understand it completely

Comment: Too much missing.  You don't show where you are drawing the text.  WHen you draw the text, you will have to create a new HFONT for the new LOGFONT change and select that font into the HDC (or CDC in MFC).  If you're just putting the text in an edit control, then you'll have to call SetFont() on the edit control.  But, there is not enough here to make a suggestion.  We need to know how pDoc->m_lf is used.

Comment: Attention:  a `LOGFONT` is not a font, but a summary about a `CFont` font's attributes! Consequently,  just assigning a `LOGFONT` variable alone will do nothing!

Comment: By the way, why are you assuming that a doc property will change a control's behaviour? It is utterly non-sense!

Comment: What you need is to have a `CFont` member variable on the `CTxtDlg` form instead of a `LOGFONT`. And instead of the `l_font.CreateFontIndirect(&m_lf); pDoc->m_lf = dlg.m_lf;` in the View you need to do `m_txtEdit.SetFont(&m_font);` in `CTxtDlg`. Implement a method `SetEditFont` on `CTxtDlg` that just does this, and then call it form the View.